# Is it possible to add computers in a particular IP range to a particular Active Directory group?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, group-policy

I'm using AWS and have a VPC which is connected to the local network via a VPN. I can launch EC2 instances, put them in various subnets in various AZ's and connect to them via internal IP.

I can also join them to the local domain.

However, I want to be able to automatically put them into specific groups within the AD domain, based on their IP address, when they join the domain.

Therefore, when I create a new instance of my image it will be joined to the domain and because it has a particular IP address, will be added to a certain group.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What are you using to auto-join these instances?

Comment: I'm pre-empting this slightly. I'm still setting up servers and joining them manually, but whether automatically joined, or joined manually I'd still like it to be added to the correct group.

Comment: What comes to mind immediately is a simple PowerShell script to check the IP, and conditionally add to a group on that basis. I'd do it as a scheduled task on some other computer. Poll the default computers container in AD periodically, check their IPs, and add to group if applicable. You could also create a GPO to execute a group-join script on startup, and use item-level targeting or WMI filtering to only apply to your desired IP range.  This would require some lax security around permissions to do that group-join, and I don't know a way to manipulate domain groups directly via GPO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think IP's are the right thing to key off of here. Are you automatically launching your instances into the VPC? If so, you could tag them or give them a 'join_X_group' role that would let them talk to to your DC in that region. Even having a [DHCP Options Set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) that would have them come up with a specific DNS server which could be your DC and then follow http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/join_a_directory.html#join_instance to join the host to a domain with a [user-data script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html).

Alternatively, you could create a Directory (see the Workspaces panel) that replicates from your existing AD infrastructure, and join it that way.